# PowerShell USBControllerDevice

Tags: powershell, wmi

I understand what the following command is doing, but what is the purpose of the '[wmi]'?

gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |
    % {wmi} |
        Sort Manufacturer, Description,DeviceID | 
            ft Manufacturer, Description,DeviceID

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is:

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice | %{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Manufacturer, Description,DeviceID | ft Manufacturer, Description,DeviceID
```

This looks to have been taken from the example on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394505(v=vs.85).aspx but has been copied incompletely.

The `%` command is an alias for ForEach-Object.
`[wmi]` is casting the `Dependent` property of each object returned from Get-WMIObject as a WMI object.

It then sorts and outputs as a table.

To learn more about what the [wmi] part does, see this blog post: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2013/07/23/object-spell-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: I probably did copy it incorrectly, but I was only after the '[wmi]' part.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.